# fast enumeration for loop - Is there a counter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a regular `for` loop I could use `i` as the counter inside the for loop. How can I know the count number from the above?

```
for(int i=0;i<[someArray count];i++)
{
   bla = [arrayExample objectAtIndex:i];
}

for(id someObject in someArray)
    {
       bla = [arrayExample objectAtIndex:??];
    }
```

Comment: For this I typically use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`

Comment: Is this "problem" really that difficult to figure out yourself?  If this is too tough for you then you have a shock waiting for you when you try and tackle real issues...

Comment: @trojanfoe No one said it was difficult. My question started with **Is there**.

Comment: This is a legit question. The answer in python is to use `enumerate`, for example. Maybe for C programmers it's not even a minor annoyance but coming from Python, at least, I balk at having to keep track of the index myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Or better, you can use an external counter and manually increment it at every cycle, but then it would be easier to use "classical" for.

Comment: It may be easier but it's a lot slower than using fast enumeration and using your own index.

Comment: Why introduce code that is slower than what is possible. It may not be a bottle neck but why use something slow when you can use something fast just as easily.

Comment: Well, the differences we are talking about have a so small effect on performances that I would not talk about "fast" and "slow". It's probably more a matter of style. Imho, if you need the index of the current object in your loop then go for a "classical" for, otherwise feel free to use fast enumeration. I would not blame those who do not use fast enumeration at all, even if they do not really need the index of the object. IMHO.

Comment: Wow! This got accepted? A straight out wrong answer. It's not even a "this could be one way of doing it" answer. It's just completely wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a normal for loop or you can just add a counter into your current fast enumeration.

This will still have the advantage of the fast enumeration while also including the index you're currently on.

```
int index = 0;

for (id element in someArray) {
    //do stuff
    ++index;
}
```

Even better is to use the fast enumeration block method...

```
[someArray enumerateWithUsingBlock:^(id element, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop) {
    // you can do stuff in here.
    // you also get the current index for free
    // idx is the index of the current object in the array
}];
```

Comment: take care if you have `continue`s that you have to increment the `index` manually in all of those.

Comment: Gave you +1 just because i didn't like the accepted answer and i've seen you around enough times to know you're reliable. Good code.

Answer (score 3):

```
 [animationKey addObject:@"cameraIris"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"cameraIrisHollowOpen"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"cameraIrisHollowClose"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"cube"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"alignedCube"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"flip"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"alignedFlip"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"oglFlip"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"rotate"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"pageCurl"];
    [animationKey addObject:@"pageUnCurl"];

  //////////////////////////////////

    [animationKey enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *animationType = obj;

        NSLog(@"Animation type #%d is %@",idx,animationType);

    }];
```

**For your case:-**

Try like this ...

```
[someArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

           bla = [someArray objectAtIndex:idx];

        }];
```

Comment: ah nice, seems like this is the best answer actually.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is kinda against the idea of fast enum.
Fast enum uses the word "for-all". That is, you do not care the order or number of elements.
Classical for is designed exactly for what you want.

Comment: Elements of an array are in order with a fast enumeration loop.

Comment: True. But what I meant is that you do not really care.
But you are right, order is there.

Answer (score 1):

why would you do that? you have this object already as `someObject`.

Anyway, if you want the current index, you can do following

```
for (id someObject in someArray)
{
    int index = [someArray indexOfObject:element];
}
```

but this looks rather useless, because why would you use fast enumeration in this case?

for more methods to query an array see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Comment: You don't have to check `containsObject:`; you're getting objects out of the array already! Also note that `indexOfObject:` will only return the _first_ index. If you have multiple objects that compare equal (`NSNull` is a prime candidate here) you will get the same index for all of them.

Comment: you're right, the condition is not needed. I'm used to use `indexOfObject:` with `containsObject:` for safety, but this is no real usecase anyway I guess :)

Comment: what makes it unsafe ,when not using `containsObject`?Here the reference is getting from the array

Comment: -1: this turns your `O(n)` loop into an `O(n^2)` loop... and isn't even always correct.

Answer (score 0):

`[arrayExample objectAtIndex:i]` is used to get the instance of object at that index in array to a reference,Fast enumeration do it in the loop itself as it return the reference of object in the array

```
for(id someObject in someArray)
{
   bla =(BlaClass *)someObject;
}
```

OR

```
for(BlaClass *someObject in someArray)
{ 
  //someobject is the reference ,just use it

}
```

Comment: you can use `BlaClass` instead of `id` directly, then there's no need to cast and then use `someObject` as reference.